# Am I querying my MySQL table correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to write a query that will join 2 tables and then return a single value. One of the tables is `wp_users`. The other is a table I made called `wp_fd_braintree_users` (I prefixed it with "wp_", this means I can use `$wpdb->prefix.` right?). This table will store another ID that is unique to every user of my site.

I can't figure out what `$wpdb->query()` is used for. The Codex mentions it but I can't find where it explains what it's used for. I also know that I need to use `$wpdb->prepare()`, but I don't understand how to write the 2nd argument to this function. How does the code below look? Can I even use `query()` and `prepare()` on a custom table?

```
<?php

    $user_id = (need to find some function that returns the current user's ID...)

    $query = $wpdb->query(prepare(

    "
    SELECT
      wp_fd_braintree_users.bt_id

    FROM
      wp_fd_braintree_users
      INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_fd_braintree_users.ID = wp_users.ID

    WHERE
      wp_users.ID = $user_id
    "

    ));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply runs the sql query you proivded. Please check [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) documentation for more details. Prepare is used to prepare SQL statement and you cannot these functions without wpdb object because they are not standard PHP functions; they are the members of WPDB class in wordpress.

Here is the correct(in case $user_id can be used for SQL injection):

```
<?php
$query = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT wp_fd_braintree_users.bt_id FROM
      wp_fd_braintree_users INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_fd_braintree_users.ID = wp_users.ID WHERE wp_users.ID = %d;", $user_id));
?>
```

Now as far as your `$user_id = get_current_user_id();` is concerned, I hope you're not calling this function too early. What wordpress documentation meant is that if you're calling your code before `init` hook is available it may cause issue because necessary data required by this function is not set yet. Mostly in in a template file you can use it freely, however if you're using it functions.php or any file required by it, you should ensure this function is not being called too early.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the 2nd part! Really cleared things up!!

Answer (score 0):

To get current/logged user id

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

Comment: Ah, yea I just stumbled onto this on Google. However, it says that I need to [use an action hook such as `init` to call this function, otherwise bad stuff will happen.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) Do you agree with this or can I simply use it like you did above?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat [Read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id)

Comment: Yea, that's what I linked. It says to use it on an init hook.

Answer (score 0):

But if you don't have a database already set you would have to do

```
SELECT database_name.bt_id FROM table name...
```

That could be a contributing error. Then insert that code into a function and set the persons name email or whatever into the arguments part of the function, have the function return $wpdb variable and it should return the value retrieved from the database.

Comment: Would it be easier if I simply updated the `wp_users` table with the other ID ? Or can we not add new fields to built in Wordpress tables?

Comment: I am not sure. I have never used Wordpress. I self host on LAMP. Maybe they have tech assistance or something. I assume that you should be able to. You might have to create and brand new table with the same name or just change the code after you make the new table with the new field.